# Ruby defined? returns nil when checking a defined attribute?

Tags: ruby

I have a class Deal < ActiveResource that has an attribute options bound from the resource.
I confirmed that options returns an array, in rails console.
However, defined?(options) returns nil.
Though I noticed that defined?(:options) returns true, I still don't understand why the nil was returned in the previous example.

Comment: Can you show a more complete code sample?

Comment: Just to be clear, `defined?(:options)` will always return a truthy value because `:options` is an expression resulting in an instance of class `Symbol`, and is therefore indeed defined. It has nothing to do with your class specifically.

Comment: Brandan is correct. No matter what the symbol is, defined?(:anything) always returns true.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I rember ActiveResource does its little magic using the `method_missing` method. So in fact you should not be expecting the method `options` to be defined. You may have a look at the [implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c2193c11ad215d3a2d7d35960630b3e1902a5082/activeresource/lib/active_resource/base.rb#L1456) to see how this works.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `defined?(options)` is calling the options method and passing the result to `defined?`. `defined?(:options)` is what you probably want. Providing a code snippet might help in answering more accurately.

Comment: To clarify, defined?(:options) always returns true no matter what options is.  So the question becomes how defined?(options) returns nil when self.options does return a non-empty array.

Comment: As Ivaylo suggested, self.options is probably implemented using method_missing and is not an actual method. Does respond_to?(:options) return true? If not, then it is implemented using method_missing. If it returns true, it could still mean that respond_to? has been overriden to be consistent with method_missing